# Add Join Management and UpdateCursor in Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, cursor, attribute-joins, update

How to join multiple table with shapefile, update cursor specific field of the table in shapefile table and remove the join table? I write some script but it not work, please correct my script.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = r'D:\DATABASE\CORONAVIRUS_UPDATE\Shapefile\COVID-19 April2020.gdb' # Here is all the table.
fc = r'D:\DATABASE\CORONAVIRUS_UPDATE\COVID19_Database.gdb\April_Cases_Deaths_Recovered\Apr_Number_Cases'
def Main_Task():
    for fieldname in field_name:
        tables = arcpy.ListTables()
        for tb in tables:
            field_text = []
            jion_fc = arcpy.AddJoin_management(fc,"Country_Name", tb, "Country__Other", "KEEP_COMMON")
            join_cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(jion_fc,["Country_Name",fieldname,"Total_Cases"])
            for x in join_cursor:
                row[1] = row[2]
                jion_cursor.updateRow(row)
                print tb
            arcpy.RemoveJoin_management(jion_fc)
```

Note for this script I use two def. One for the fieldname container and second is the main task here I attached. If there is better way for this project?

Comment: We probably need more details on what you are attempting and what 'not work' means.  You have a typo in the cursor name, and are attempting an `updateRow` with a `da.SearchCursor`, so this can't work as-is, but `da.UpdateCursor` can change more than one row at a time, so re-rolling your loops seems indicated.

Comment: Correction: `UpdateCursor` can change more than one ***column*** at a time, so if you organize one big join, you can make just one pass (N times faster than N passes)

Comment: I don't think update cursor will work at all on table with joins. It's much more efficient to create dictionary from table to be joined and read from it, when iterating with update cursor.

Comment: The code that you're presenting seems more like a copy/paste from your code than a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) which would make it much easier to get help.